# Azure monitor resource upscales

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-monitoring

I am monitoring a few Azure subscriptions that contain a lot of resources that are used by a lot of users. I want to be notified if these users change or upscale their resources. For example, if user A upscales their PaaS database from a basic (S0) pricing tier to a more expensive standard or premium pricing tier, I want to get a notification. The amount of resources that are used within the azure environment are too many to manually check, hence my question.

Anyone have a suggestion for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using an Activity Log Alert to accomplish this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-activity-log-alerts

First, you'll want to generate the action you want to get alerted off of yourself (eg. go scale up a VMSS). Next, head to the Activity Log in the portal, giving a few minutes for the event to show up. Once it shows up in the Activity Log, click the event and in the blade that appears in the bottom half of the window, click "Add Activity Log alert." This will pre-fill the Activity Log alert with all the details from that event.

Now, you'll want to generalize the alert so that it isn't specific to that one resource. In the blade for creating the Activity Log alert, keep the operation name as it was filled in automatically and the category, but remove other auto-filled details like the level, resource name, and resource group (since you want the alert to fire on any resource in the subscription). Create an Action Group that defines the email addresses, webhooks, and SMS numbers you want to receive the notification, and save it.

If there are multiple actions that you want to alert off of, eg. scaling up on a VMSS, or a web app, or a database, you'll want to repeat this process, creating an Activity Log alert for each unique operation name (an operation name has a 1:1 mapping to a resource type). However, you can target the same Action Group from all of these alerts so if you need to modify who receives the notifications you can do it centrally from the common Action Group.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much John! I will look into this but this seems exactly what I'm looking for!